# Cannot write data to struct

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, typedef, ini

qq4all.
I have a task - write config parser for syntax like this:

```
[module]
name = first
imitationType = first

[module]
name = second
imitationType = second
```

etc.
I found pretty config parser - [inih](https://code.google.com/p/inih/), but I can't force it to work as I want. Here my code, writed over inih example:

```
typedef struct {
    const char* name;
    const char* imitation_type;
} module_config;

int module_count = 0;

static int handler(void* user, const char* section, const char* name,
                   const char* value)
{
    module_config* pconfig = (module_config*)user;
    pconfig = (module_config *) malloc(module_count*sizeof(module_config));
    #define MATCH(s, n) strcmp(section, s) == 0 && strcmp(name, n) == 0
    if (strcmp(section, "module") == 0) {
        if (MATCH("module", "name")) {
            pconfig[module_count]->version = strdup(value);
        } else if (MATCH("module", "imitationType")) {
            pconfig[module_count]->name = strdup(value);
        } else {
            return 0;  /* unknown section/name, error */
        }
    ++module_count;
    pconfig = (module_config *) realloc(pconfig, module_count * sizeof(module_config));
}

return 1;
}
```

But, when I trying to compile this, I get next error:

> Error! Expression for '->' must be 'pointer to struct or union'

for those lines:

```
pconfig[module_count]->version = strdup(value);
pconfig[module_count]->name = strdup(value);
```

I'm newbie in programming, and don't understand, why this happens. Please, help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pconfig is a pointer to an instance of the module_config struct.

Using pconfig[module_count] on this pointer is equivalent to dereferencing the pointer `(pconfig+module_count)`, i.e. it is equivalent to `*(pconfig+module_count)`.

Thus, `pconfig[module_count]` is no longer a pointer. You need to use `pconfig[module_count].version` or `(pconfig+module_count)->version`.